# htaccess default page according calling domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have hosting space where 2 different domains point to.

Say "firstdomain.com" and "seconddomain.com".

I would like that if I digit "firstdomain.com", it opens /shop.php page, while digiting "seconddomain.com" it goes to /index.php

I have tried setting the default page with htaccess by doing:

```
DirectoryIndex shop.php
```

It works, but I do not know how to "split" that behaviour.

Can that be done via htaccess? How would do you do it?

Thank you

Comment: you could use mod_rewrite for this, but why not just have two `<virtualhost>` definitions, each with its own doc root definition?

Comment: from my cpanel I cannot create virtualhost. I can create aliases. I do not know wether they are the same think though. I cannot assign a different folder or file to an alias. The default landing folder is public_html. always.

Comment: no idea if it's legal syntax, but there is `<If>`, so maybe something like `<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == "first.com">direcdtoryindex ...<else>...</if>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's ok for `seconddomain.com` with `index.php`, you can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} firstdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ shop.php [L]
```